# Syntax error with CONSTRAINT on MySQL that worked on postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, syntax

The professor gave a .sql file to do some exercises, here is a piece of it:

CREATE TABLE DEPT

```
   (DEPTNO NUMERIC(2) CONSTRAINT PK_DEPT PRIMARY KEY, (error 1)
DNAME VARCHAR(14),
LOC VARCHAR(13) );
```

CREATE TABLE EMP

```
   (EMPNO NUMERIC(4) CONSTRAINT PK_EMP PRIMARY KEY, (error 2)
ENAME VARCHAR(10),
JOB VARCHAR(9),
HIREDATE DATE,
SAL NUMERIC(7,2),
DEPTNO NUMERIC(2) CONSTRAINT FK_DEPTNO REFERENCES DEPT); (error 3)
```

We runned the file in class with pgadmin 3 and everything went fine, but I downloaded MySQL instead of postgres to continue the exercises at home and it gives an error: "unexpected constraint". Since it works with postgres but not in MySQL maybe is a syntax error with MySQL?

Comment: Every DB engine uses a slightly different syntax. You can't just run the same SQL code on all engines.

Comment: MySQL supports various syntaxes, but apparently not that one. I'm use to the more verbose form `CONSTRAINT name FOREIGN KEY (columnOfThisTable) REFERENCES ThatTable (columnOfThatTable)`. I think that works in MySQL and most other databases. Not sure about Postgres, but probably there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do more verbose, And every `rdbms` are different.. You can't use statement you work in some `rdbms` to other `rdbms`

*Table Dept*

```
CREATE TABLE DEPT
(DEPTNO NUMERIC(2),
DNAME VARCHAR(14),
LOC VARCHAR(13), 
CONSTRAINT PK_DEPT PRIMARY KEY (DEPTNO));
```

*Table Emp*

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
(EMPNO NUMERIC(4),
ENAME VARCHAR(10),
JOB VARCHAR(9),
HIREDATE DATE,
SAL NUMERIC(7,2),
DEPTNO NUMERIC(2), 
CONSTRAINT PK_EMP PRIMARY KEY (EMPNO),
CONSTRAINT FK_DEPTNO FOREIGN KEY (DEPTNO) REFERENCES DEPT(DEPTNO));
```

Comment: Now only the last line that doesn't work. But the other two errors vanished.

Comment: @Pinteco my bad.. You can check up again.. :)

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL's acceptable formats](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) for foreign keys are described within their extensive documentation.

Other CONSTRAINT options are [also shown in the documents](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html)

For example, PRIMARY KEY:

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] PRIMARY KEY [index_type] (key_part,...)
      [index_option] ...
```

As part of a CREATE TABLE, this can go at the end for FOREIGN KEY checks.

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT
```